# InvalidProgramException on Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

During the development of desktop Windows Form application we faced the following problem:
our client has several production machines where the application is installed, on one of these machines
.NET runtime throws InvalidProgramException with the following stack trace:

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.GetColumnAtDisplayIndex(Int32 displayIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CorrectColumnFrozenState(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, Int32 anticipatedColumnIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnAddingColumn(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.Add(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CorrectColumnFrozenStates(DataGridViewColumn[] dataGridViewColumns)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnAddingColumns(DataGridViewColumn[] dataGridViewColumns)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.AddRange(DataGridViewColumn[] dataGridViewColumns)
```

On other machines we don't observe such exception.

- Could you please advice what can be the cause for this exception?
- Is it related to broken .NET runtime installation?
- What steps can we take to resolve the problem?

I've started investigation with the fact that .NET Framework dll, that are installed on a machine, are processed by ngen (native image generator) and are loaded from Native Images Cache. This is how it works on my dev machine.

- The question is, if System.Windows.Forms dll is loaded as native code then why exception is about invalid MSIL ?
- Is there any way to check installed .NET Framework libraries dll for integrity?
- Is there any chances that this problem is in compiler used by ngen? Can I somehow force regeneration of .NET Framework native images?

Platform:
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045
System Type x64-based PC

.NET runtime preinstalled on PC: 4.8.04084 (528 372)
Project target .NET Framework: 4.6.2

Comment: Ask IT staff to replace/re-image the machine.

Comment: @HansPassant is there any official documentation how it can be done? As far as I know .NET Framework can't be uninstalled on a machine.

Comment: Looks like I found something: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/dotnet/framework/general/repair-installation

Thank you for your reply.